# Optimal algorithm to solve this maze?

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently stuck on a challenge our lecturer gave us over at our university. We've been looking at the most popular pathfinding algorithms such as Dijkstra and A*. Although, I think this challenge exercise requires something else and it has me stumped.

A visual representation of the maze that needs solving:

[image: Maze]

**Color legend** 
Blue = starting node 
Gray = path 
Green = destination node

The way it's supposed to be solved is that when movement is done, it has to be done until it collides with either the edge of the maze or an obstacle (the black borders). It would also need to be solved in the least amount of row-movements possible (in this case 7)

My question: Could someone push me in the right direction on what algorithm to look at? I think Dijkstra/A* is not the way to go, considering the shortest path is not always the **correct** path given the assignment.

Comment: It is. your example shows 7 edges each of cost 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still solvable with Dijkstra / A*, what needs to be changed is the configuration of neighbors.

---

A little background, first:

Dijkstra and A* are general path finding algorithms formulated on graphs. When, instead of a graph, we have a character moving on a grid, it might not be that obvious where the graph is. But it's still there, and one way to construct a graph would be the following:

- the nodes of the graph correspond to the cells of the grid
- there are edges between nodes corresponding to neighboring cells.

Actually, in most problems involving some configurations and transitions between them, it is possible to construct a corresponding graph, and apply Dijkstra/A*. Thus, it is also possible to tackle problems such as [sliding puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle), [rubik's cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube), etc., which apparently differ significantly from a character moving on a grid. But they have states, and transitions between states, thus it is possible to try graph search methods (these methods, especially the uninformed ones such as Dijkstra's algorithm, might not always be feasible due to the large search space, but in principle it's possible to apply them).

---

In the problem that you mentioned, the graph would not differ much from the one with typical character movements:

- the nodes can still be the cells of the grid
- there will now be edges from a node to nodes corresponding to valid movements (ending near a border or an obstacle), which, in this case, will not always coincide with the four spatial immediate neighbors of the grid cell.

---

As pointed by Tamas Hegedus in the comments section, it's not obvious what heuristic function should be chosen if A* is used.

The standard heuristics based on Manhattan or Euclidean distance would not be valid here, as they might over-estimate the distance to the target.

One valid heuristic would be *id*(row != destination_row) + *id*(col != destination_col), where *id* is the identity function, with *id*(false) = 0 and *id*(true) = 1.

Comment: And what heuristic function would you use?

Comment: @TamasHegedus nice question, the standard heuristics (based on manhattan, euclidean distance) would not be valid here, as they would over-estimate the distance to target. One valid choice, would be id(row != destination_row) + id(columnn != destination_column), where id is the identity function with id(true) = 1 and id(false) = 0. I don't think it's extremely useful, but it's valid and maybe slightly better than providing no information. I'll keep thinking :) let me know if you have an idea (or maybe a different question should be asked separately).

Comment: Hello I tried implementing this idea with the given heuristic formula, and while it works on this maze example, it doesn't work on other examples. Have you given some thought to a possible heuristic that works for any maze? :)

Comment: Hello, yes, the heuristic should work for any maze, probably the mistake is somewhere else. You can also try setting heuristic = 0, which is also valid (although it's not very interesting, making A* behave just like Dijkstra's algorithm), just for test -- does A* still has problems in that case?

Comment: @qwertyman Here's another maze: http://prntscr.com/f2vege
I added the edges in orange color, blue is the starting node, green the destination node.. I've also added the F-cost for the starting node's edges.
The H-cost is being calculated as you mentioned. The G-cost I kept the same: the distance between the target node from the edge and the startingNode (getTarget().distance(destination)). Any ideas?

Comment: I think that there is a mistake regarding G-cost. It's value should always be the cost of the path so far (from the starting node). So for both nodes which are reachable in one step from the start, the G-cost should be 1. The H-cost for the orange node marked with "7,0" should be 1 (because it has different columns with the destination), so its total F-cost should be 2. Regarding the bottom right node, the H-cost should be 2 (because it has both different row and different column from the destination), thus its F-cost should be 3 (= G + H = 1 + 2)

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra/A* are fine. What you need is to carefully think about what you consider graph nodes and graph edges.

Standing in the blue cell (lets call it `5,5`), you have three valid moves:

- move one cell to the right (to `6,5`)
- move four cells to the left (to `1,5`)
- move five cells up (to `5,1`)

Note that you *can't* go from `5,5` to `4,5` or `5,4`. Apply the same reasoning to new nodes (eg from `5,1` you can go to `1,1`, `10,1` and `5,5`) and you will get a graph on which you run your Dijkstra/A*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate every possible move and take the move that results with the minimum distance.  Something like the following:

```
int minDistance(int x, int y, int prevX, int prevY, int distance) {
  if (CollionWithBorder(x, y)  // can't take this path
    return int.MAX_VALUE;

  if (NoCollionWithBorder(x, y)  // it's OK to take this path
  {
    // update the distance only when there is a long change in direction
    if (LongDirectionChange(x, y, prevX, prevY))
      distance = distance + 1;
  )

  if (ReachedDestination(x, y)  // we're done
    return distance;

  // find the path with the minimum distance      
  return min(minDistance(x, y + 1, x, y, distance),  // go right
             minDistance(x + 1, y, x, y, distance),  // go up
             minDistance(x - 1, y, x, y, distance),  // go down
             minDistance(x, y - 1, x, y, distance)); // go left
}

bool LongDirectionChange(x, y, prevX, prevY) {
  if (y-2 == prevY && x == prevX) ||(y == prevY && x-2 == prevX)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

This is assuming diagonal moves are not allowed.  If they are, add them to the min() call:

```
  minDistance(x + 1, y + 1, distance),  // go up diagonally to right
  minDistance(x - 1, y - 1, distance),  // go down diagonally to left
  minDistance(x + 1, y - 1, distance),  // go up diagonally to left
  minDistance(x - 1, y + 1, distance),  // go down diagonally to right
```

Comment: this would be correct for the typical cases, but in the specific problem posed here, the agent incurs a single unit of cost for a long movement (until the first obstacle) along a single row / column.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I edited the code to change how to increment the distance when we're moving along a row or column.